# Adding to map as attribute in a record f#

Tags: dictionary, types, f#, functional-programming

I have this type:

```
type Model = {Ships: map<Mmsi, Ship>}
type Ship = {Latitude: float Longitude: float Speed: float Heading: float}
```

I am trying to figure out a way to add to the ship map through a message type

`type msg = {Latitude: float Longitude: float Mmsi = int Time = string}`

Using this function:

```
let update (msg : Msg) (currentModel : Model) : Model =
    // TODO: implement the new model based on the received message here
    let currentModel = 
        { 
            Ships = Map.Add(msg.Mmsi, msgToShip msg)
        }
    currentModel
```

However I am getting an error from the compiler as such: "Method or object constructor 'Add' is not static.

I am not especially experienced in f# or functional programming in general so any pointers to this would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capitalized `Add` is an instance method on the type `Map<_, _>`. Lowercase `add` is a function in the `Map` module. So what you wanted to call here was:

```
Ships = Map.add msg.Mmsi (msgToShip msg) currentModel.Ships
```

Or, also valid but less idiomatic:

```
Ships = currentModel.Ships.Add(msg.Mmsi, msgToShip msg)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!